# Cloud Firestore: Filtering documents over today's date in a cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have stored in Firestore documents with createdAt field containing date and timezone of the user. For example(December 22, 2019 at 9:21:42 PM UTC-3)

Then, I have a cloud functions where I want to retrieve all of **Today** documents. The problem is that the cloud function doesn't know the Timezone, and that gets messy when retrieveng documents of diferent timezones.

```
const now: Date = new Date();

const docQuery = await db
   .collection('users')
   .where('createdAt', '>', new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()))
   .where('createdAt', '<', new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 23, 59, 59))
   .get();
```

The `now` date is in UTC-0 and if I have a document from the day before at 22:00 UTC-3, the query retrieves it, but technically it is not a Today document.

Any idea on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: You will have to initialize the Date object with the specific timezone you want. Or, you will have to use some other library to help with that.

Comment: I understand, so a proper solution would be that the frontend send a parameter to de cloud functions with the required timezone of the device and use that to create the Date for the query, is that correct? Thanks @DougStevenson

Comment: Yes, you will need to get a timezone (or the specific date time in milliseconds to convert to a date) from whoever defines what a "day" is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `timestamp` inside the firestore documents instead of date.

```
ref.doc(key).set({
  created : firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date("December 10, 1815 19:00:00 EST"))
})
```

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

You can then use the method [`toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#to-date) to convert the timestamp to a Date object.

Comment: And how could I do it if the dateTime was selected by the user?

Comment: Check this https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data

Comment: `var docData = {
    stringExample: "Hello world!",
    booleanExample: true,
    numberExample: 3.14159265,
    dateExample: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date("December 10, 1815")),
    arrayExample: [5, true, "hello"],
    nullExample: null,
    objectExample: {
        a: 5,
        b: {
            nested: "foo"
        }
    }
};
db.collection("data").doc("one").set(docData).then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
});`

Comment: So doing `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date("December 10, 1815")),` will ignore the date timezone?

Comment: Firestore server timestamps are not going to help when it comes to querying.  They are only used for setting a field value to the current moment in time.  The query needs to provide the precise moment in time for the query, either through a Date object, or a Timestamp object.

Comment: @DougStevenson doesn't this give a timestamp object `var docData = { stringExample: "Hello world!", booleanExample: true, numberExample: 3.14159265, dateExample: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date("December 10, 1815")), arrayExample: [5, true, "hello"], nullExample: null, objectExample: { a: 5, b: { nested: "foo" } } }; db.collection("data").doc("one").set(docData).then(function() { console.log("Document successfully written!"); })`

Comment: @DougStevenson `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date("December 10, 1815"))`

Comment: The code in your answer is showing a server timestamp for setting a field.  Your comment here is showing something very different.

Comment: But when I read ur comment first(before you edit the comment) I thought we can't use timestamp for querying in firestore, that's why i undeleted the answer to ask you @DougStevenson

Comment: You can use a timestamp, but the code you're showing now still doesn't provide a timezone for the date, which is what the OP is asking about. The marked duplicate here explains how to do that.